# ASP.NET Core MVC: return a method in another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I get a `NullReferenceException` when I try to create a new `Contract` when executing my program. I get the error at the method where I want to return the model. But I don't know why and I can't find out because I'm a bit new to programming.

This is my model where I want to return the calculated price from the `CarList` model

```
public class Contract 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CarListId{get;set;}
    public  CarList CarList { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime AusleihDatum{ get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime AbgabeDatum { get; set; }
    
    public int KilometerstandAnfang { get; set; }
    public int KilometerstandEnde { get; set; }

    public double GesamtPreis
    {
        get
        {
            return CarList.GesamtPreis();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `CarList` model:

```
namespace MvcCar2.Models
{
    public class CarList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Hersteller { get; set; }
        public string Modell { get; set; }
        public string Kennzeichen { get; set; }
        public string Farbe { get; set; }

        public int Kilometerstand { get; set; }

        public int CarGroupId { get; set; }
        public CarGroup CarGroup { get; set; }
        
        [NotMapped]
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }
        
        public double GesamtPreis()
        {
            if (Contract.AbgabeDatum < Contract.AusleihDatum)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Return date is before rental date");
            }
           
            TimeSpan differenz = Contract.AbgabeDatum - Contract.AusleihDatum;
            int ausleihzeit = (int)differenz.TotalDays;
            double gesamtPreis1 = ausleihzeit * CarGroup.PreisTag;
            
            return gesamtPreis1;
        }
    }
}
```

My `ContractsController`:

```
namespace MvcCar2.Controllers
{
    public class ContractsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MvcCar2Context _context;

        public ContractsController(MvcCar2Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Contracts
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var mvcCar2Context = _context.Contract
                                         .Include(c => c.CarList)
                                         .Include(c => c.Customer)
                                         .Include(c => c.CarList.CarGroup);
            return View(await mvcCar2Context.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Contract == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var contract = await _context.Contract
                .Include(c => c.CarList)
                .Include(c => c.Customer)
                .Include(c=> c.CarList.CarGroup)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (contract == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(contract);
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var CarListfromDB = _context.Car.ToList();
            
            var CarListList = CarListfromDB.Select(Car => new
            {
                Id = Car.Id,
                DisplayText1 =
                $"{Car.Hersteller}-{Car.Modell}-{Car.Farbe}-{Car.Kennzeichen}-{Car.CarGroupId}"
            });

            ViewData["CarListId"] = new SelectList(CarListList, "Id", "DisplayText1");

            var CustomerfromDB = _context.Customer.ToList();

            var CustomerList = CustomerfromDB.Select(Customer => new
            {
                Id =Customer.Id,
                DisplayText2 =
                $"{Customer.Name}-{Customer.Vorname}-{Customer.EMail}-{Customer.AdressId}"
            });

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(CustomerList, "Id", "DisplayText2");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Contracts/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id, [Bind("Id,CustomerId,CarListId,AusleihDatum,AbgabeDatum,GesamtPreis,KilometerstandAnfang,KilometerstandEnde")] Contract contract)
        {
            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
                _context.Add(contract);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}

            var CarListfromDB = _context.Car.ToList();
            var CarListList = CarListfromDB.Select(Car => new
            {
                Id = Car.Id,
                DisplayText1 =
                $"{Car.Hersteller}---{Car.Modell}---{Car.CarGroupId}---{Car.Kennzeichen}---{Car.Farbe}"
            });

            ViewData["CarListId"] = new SelectList(CarListList, "Id", "DisplayText1");
            var CustomerfromDB = _context.Customer.ToList();

            var CustomerList = CustomerfromDB.Select(Customer => new
            {
                Id = Customer.Id,
                DisplayText2 =
                $"{Customer.Name}---{Customer.Vorname}---{Customer.EMail}---{Customer.AdressId}"
            });

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(CustomerList, "Id", "DisplayText2");
            
            return View(contract);
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Contract == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var contract = await _context.Contract.FindAsync(id);

            if (contract == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var CarListfromDB = _context.Car.ToList();

            var CarListList = CarListfromDB.Select(Car => new
            {
                Id = Car.Id,
                DisplayText1 =
                $"{Car.Hersteller}---{Car.Modell}---{Car.CarGroupId}---{Car.Kennzeichen}---{Car.Farbe}"
            });

            ViewData["CarListId"] = new SelectList(CarListList, "Id", "DisplayText1", contract.CarListId);
            var CustomerfromDB = _context.Customer.ToList();

            var CustomerList = CustomerfromDB.Select(Customer => new
            {
                Id = Customer.Id,
                DisplayText2 =
                $"{Customer.Name}---{Customer.Vorname}---{Customer.EMail}---{Customer.AdressId}"
            });

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(CustomerList, "Id", "DisplayText2", contract.CustomerId);

            return View(contract);
        }

        // POST: Contracts/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,CustomerId,CarListId,AusleihDatum,AbgabeDatum,GesamtPreis,KilometerstandAnfang,KilometerstandEnde")] Contract contract)
        {
            if (id != contract.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(contract);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ContractExists(contract.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}
            var CarListfromDB = _context.Car.ToList();

            var CarListList = CarListfromDB.Select(Car => new
            {
                Id = Car.Id,
                DisplayText1 =
                $"{Car.Hersteller}---{Car.Modell}---{Car.CarGroupId}---{Car.Kennzeichen}---{Car.Farbe}"
            });

            ViewData["CarListId"] = new SelectList(CarListList, "Id", "DisplayText1", contract.CarListId);
            var CustomerfromDB = _context.Customer.ToList();

            var CustomerList = CustomerfromDB.Select(Customer => new
            {
                Id = Customer.Id,
                DisplayText2 =
                $"{Customer.Name}---{Customer.Vorname}---{Customer.EMail}---{Customer.AdressId}"
            });

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(CustomerList, "Id", "DisplayText2", contract.CustomerId);
            return View(contract);
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Contract == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var contract = await _context.Contract
                .Include(c => c.CarList)
                .Include(c => c.Customer)
                .Include (c => c.CarList.CarGroup)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (contract == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(contract);
        }

        // POST: Contracts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Contract == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'MvcCar2Context.Contract'  is null.");
            }

            var contract = await _context.Contract.FindAsync(id);

            if (contract != null)
            {
                _context.Contract.Remove(contract);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ContractExists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.Contract?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

My `CarListController`:

```
namespace MvcCar2.Controllers
{
    public class CarListsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MvcCar2Context _context;

        public CarListsController(MvcCar2Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: CarLists
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var mvcCar2Context = _context.Car.Include(c => c.CarGroup);
            return View(await mvcCar2Context.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: CarLists/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Car == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var carList = await _context.Car
                .Include(c => c.CarGroup)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (carList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(carList);
        }

        // GET: CarLists/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
           var CarGroupfromDB = _context.CarGroup.ToList();

            var CarGroupList = CarGroupfromDB.Select(CarGroup => new
            {
                Id = CarGroup.Id,
                DisplayText = $"{CarGroup.Klasse}-{CarGroup.PreisTag}"
            });
   
            ViewData["CarGroupId"] = new SelectList(CarGroupList, "Id", "DisplayText");

            return View();
        }

        // POST: CarLists/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Hersteller,Modell,Kennzeichen,Farbe,Kilometerstand,CarGroupId")] CarList carList)
        {
            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
                _context.Add(carList);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}
            
            var CarGroupfromDB = _context.CarGroup.ToList();

            var CarGroupList = CarGroupfromDB.Select(CarGroup => new
            {
                Id = CarGroup.Id,
                DisplayText =
             $"{CarGroup.Klasse}-{CarGroup.PreisTag}"
            });

            ViewData["CarGroupId"] = new SelectList(CarGroupList, "Id", "DisplayText");

            return View(carList);
        }

        // GET: CarLists/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Car == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var carList = await _context.Car.FindAsync(id);

            if (carList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var CarGroupfromDB = _context.CarGroup.ToList();

            var CarGroupList = CarGroupfromDB.Select(CarGroup => new
            {
                Id = CarGroup.Id,
                DisplayText =
             $"{CarGroup.Klasse}-{CarGroup.PreisTag}"
            });

            ViewData["CarGroupId"] = new SelectList(CarGroupList, "Id", "DisplayText", carList.CarGroupId);

            return View(carList);
        }

        // POST: CarLists/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Hersteller,Modell,Kennzeichen,Farbe,Kilometerstand,CarGroupId")] CarList carList)
        {
            if (id != carList.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(carList);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CarListExists(carList.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}
            var CarGroupfromDB = _context.CarGroup.ToList();

            var CarGroupList = CarGroupfromDB.Select(CarGroup => new
            {
                Id = CarGroup.Id,
                DisplayText =
             $"{CarGroup.Klasse}-{CarGroup.PreisTag}"
            });

            ViewData["CarGroupId"] = new SelectList(CarGroupList, "Id", "DisplayText", carList.CarGroupId);

            return View(carList);
        }

        // GET: CarLists/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Car == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var carList = await _context.Car
                .Include(c => c.CarGroup)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (carList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(carList);
        }

        // POST: CarLists/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Car == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'MvcCar2Context.Car'  is null.");
            }

            var carList = await _context.Car.FindAsync(id);

            if (carList != null)
            {
                _context.Car.Remove(carList);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool CarListExists(int id)
        {
          return (_context.Car?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `CarGroup` model where I get the price from:

```
namespace MvcCar2.Models
{
    public class CarGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Klasse { get; set; }

        public double PreisTag { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is calculate the price in the `CarList` model. The model takes the price from the `Cargroup` model based on the `CarGroup` and then this calculated price is returned in the `ContractController` so it will be shown in the table of the `ContractsController`.

Comment: I tested with your code, the carlist is null in your model contract, that causes the NullReferenceException. Your GesamtPreis in the contract only get but not set, which will surely make it null. I suggest you query on the GesamtPreis in your Create post action to get the value and move the GesamtPreis out of contract.

Comment: Could you please set the breakpoint and provide more debug details?

Comment: @Ronaldoz I think its because i have to load the data from the carList Database but i dont know how yet. Like How i connect the models

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no debug details, I can give you one possible cause.

The contract model calls carlist for the price property, but when creating, the model haven’t bound the carlist, that’s why it will always throw the NullReferenceException. You can follow my sample to check.

> 1. Your contract references the customer and carlist, set the property to be nullable. And check the price.

```
Contract.cs

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    public class Contract
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

         //1.to be nullable
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
        public int CarListId { get; set; }
        public CarList? CarList { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime AusleihDatum { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime AbgabeDatum { get; set; }

        public int KilometerstandAnfang { get; set; }
        public int KilometerstandEnde { get; set; }

        public double GesamtPreis
        {
            get
            {
                   //2.add the logic to avoid nullreference
                return CarList != null ? CarList.GesamtPreis() : 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 2. Your Create action should bind price no more

```
ContractsController
// POST: Contracts/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id, [Bind("Id,CustomerId,CarListId,AusleihDatum,AbgabeDatum,KilometerstandAnfang,KilometerstandEnde")] Contract contract)
{
    // 1.The modelstate will be invalid if the customer and carlist are not nullable
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(contract);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         //2.Here you can get the price and it will be bound to model
         //3.Include will connect the reference model in efcore
        var SavedContract = await _context.Contract
        .Include(c => c.CarList)
        .Include(c => c.Customer)
        .Include(c => c.CarList.CarGroup)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(C => C.CarListId == contract.CarListId);
        var gesamtPreis = SavedContract.GesamtPreis;

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    var CarListfromDB = _context.Car.ToList();
    var CarListList = CarListfromDB.Select(Car => new
    {
        Id = Car.Id,
        DisplayText1 =
        $"{Car.Hersteller}---{Car.Modell}---{Car.CarGroupId}---{Car.Kennzeichen}---{Car.Farbe}"
    });

    ViewData["CarListId"] = new SelectList(CarListList, "Id", "DisplayText1");
    var CustomerfromDB = _context.Customer.ToList();

    var CustomerList = CustomerfromDB.Select(Customer => new
    {
        Id = Customer.Id,
        DisplayText2 =
        $"{Customer.Name}---{Customer.Vorname}---{Customer.EMail}---{Customer.AdressId}"
    });

    ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(CustomerList, "Id", "DisplayText2");

    return View(contract);
}
```

> 3.Since you don't offer the Customer, make sure the reference is correct

```
Customer.cs

namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Vorname { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? EMail { get; set; }
        public int AdressId { get; set; }
        public Contract? Contract { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now the price will be provided.

Test

[image]